# Email validation not working in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, email-validation

In my MVC application, email validation is working perfectly locally but when I m publishing and deploying to server It won't work. I have compared the html source of both local and deployed files and there is no difference. My Razor view mark up is

```
 <li>
        <p><strong>Email: </strong>@Model.CurrentEmailAddress <span class="deliverychange" onclick="showHidden('emailchange');">(Change email)</span></p>
        <div id="emailchange" class="fullborder" style="display: none;">
            <div class="orderrow newemailaddress">
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.UpdatedEmailAddress)
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.UpdatedEmailAddress, new { @onkeypress = "showEmailChangeConfirmation();" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.UpdatedEmailAddress)
            </div>

            <div id="updatedemailkeypress" style="display: none;">
                <div class="orderrow checkboxrow emailchangeconfirm">
                    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.UpdateEmailAddress)
                    @Html.EnumRadioButtonFor(m => m.UpdateEmailAddress, false)
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="clear">&nbsp;</div>
        </div>
    </li>
```

and my model is as

```
    [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
    [RegularExpression(@"^([\w.-]+)@([\w-]+)((.(\w){2,3})+)$", ErrorMessage = "Email is not valid")]
    [Display(Name = "Enter new email address: ")]
    public string UpdatedEmailAddress { get; set; }


    [Display(Name = "We will use ****")]
    public YesNo UpdateEmailAddress { get; set; }
```

Comment: Check if the version of ASP.NET MVC and all related assemblies is the same on your machine and the server. The data annotation attributes may behave differently between versions.

Comment: Any assemblies in particular? - As I have published the full application on the server after deleting the existing files

Comment: System.Web, System.Web.Mvc, System.Web.Razor, System.Web.Webpages. There may be more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After spending a lot of time on this I found the publish wizard is not copying the jquery.validate-vsdoc.js to the scripts folder. I manually copied this to the server and all started working.

Answer (score 2):

Use the EmailAddress-attribute instead

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.emailaddressattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Please recheck that form tag is there.

Form validation works actually by validating form valid method.
So, the form is required to be exist.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use   dataannotationsextensions library, you can download from nuget.

and just add Email attribute to your model like this

```
using DataAnnotationsExtensions;
        [Required]
        [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
        [Email]
        public string UpdatedEmailAddress { get; set; }
```